# Difficulty getting arrays to bind in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm having difficulty getting my view to bind to view model data in Knockout. Some of it binds in the application but not the nested arrays.

In an attempt to reproduce the issue as an MVCE I created [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noonand/opvprbtg/); however the MVCE functions even worse than the actual code as the current address part of it doesn't work at all. I'm hoping that this is just unfamiliarity with something in jsFiddle though.

It's JSON that's returned from a WebAPI call in ASP.NET that looks as follows (non-MVCE text removed):

```
'{"CurrentAddress":{"ResidentFrom":2010,"Address":{"OfNoFixedAbode":false,"Line1":"A","Line2":"B","Line3":"C","Line4":"D","Line5":"E","PostCode":"3C"},"FullAddress":"A, B, C, D, E, 3C"},"HasPreviousAddresses":true,"PreviousAddresses":[{"ResidentFrom":2004,"ResidentTo":2010,"Address":{"OfNoFixedAbode":false,"Line1":"K","Line2":"L","Line3":"M","Line4":"N","Line5":"O","PostCode":"2B"},"FullAddress":"K, L, M, N, O, 2B"},{"ResidentFrom":1998,"ResidentTo":2004,"Address":{"OfNoFixedAbode":false,"Line1":"F","Line2":"G","Line3":"H","Line4":"I","Line5":"J","PostCode":"1A"},"FullAddress":"F, G, H, I, J, 1A"}]}';
```

Because the page can be used in either a new or edit scenario I then test as follows:

```
if ((serverModel !== null) || (serverModel !== undefined)) {
  SetValues(viewModel, serverModel);
}
```

`SetValues` attempts to put the variables into the viewModel, but it's all fairly straightforward stuff. It should really use some kind of mapping lib, but I'm figuring that I'll get a basic version of it working first.

The entire code can be seen at the previously mentioned [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noonand/opvprbtg/)

**EDIT 2016-11-09**
I put all of this in a standalone file and ran it through F12. The error I get back is as follows:

```
"Unable to process binding \"value: function (){return CurrentAddress().Address().ResidentFrom }\"\nMessage: Function expected"
```

Comment: FYI - you've got an extraneous `)` on `viewModel.PreviousAddresses.push(previousAddress));` in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Fixed, sadly makes no difference, but thanks!

Comment: Hmm... Another possible issue - when `SetValues()` is invoked, you're not deserializing the `serverModel` before passing it to the constructor for `CurrentAddress()`, so `serverModel.CurrentAddress == undefined`.

Comment: So, if I deserialise it before sending it through, is that the best way? I updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: have you tried to use knockoutjs mapping plugin? I always use for nested binding properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is a lot of stuff going on here..

First, the `CurrentAddress` object is not being created as an observable after you parse your JSON. So change all the bindings like below -

```
<label data-bind="value: CurrentAddress.Address().ResidentFrom"></label>
```

Also, I observed that you have not defined any property named `FullAddress` but you have used it in your bindings; so it was throwing error too.

Please refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opvprbtg/89/) (Oops! I updated your original one..)

Comment: The format that I found worked for me was:    <label data-bind="text: CurrentAddress.Address().Line1"></label>

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle with a fully working version and will leave it there for posterity. I'm awarding this as the answer as, while not complete, it gave me enough of a nudge to get me over the finish line. Fingers crossed the fiddle works now when I re-integrate it :-S